# Picasso - get path of loaded image

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso in my Android application to load images from URL. These images are displayed in some `ListView`. When user clicks on some item in this `ListView`, I need to create a sharing `Intent` with selected image.

I create sharing intent with this code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(localPath));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mUrl);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.label_share)));
```

In code above, there is a local variable `localPath`. This variable has to contain path to image. I suppose that Picasso has some cache, where downloaded images are stored. Is there any way how can I retrieve the path of selected image?

**UPDATE: Partial solution**

Finally, I found a solution which works for me. But I do not know, if this is a correct solution or if better solution exists.

I created a class which implements `com.squareup.picasso.Target` interface and in method `onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom from)` I provided this implementation:

```
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImageUri = getBitmapUri(bitmap, mName));
}

private Uri getBitmapUri(Bitmap bitmap, String title) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
     String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), bitmap, title, null);
     return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

After that, I have `mImageUri` which I can pass to sharing intent. Maybe this part of code will be useful for someone.

But I don't know if better solution exist. In my solution I have to store `Bitmap` on disk, but maybe there is a same image on disk already, because Picasso loaded it. And also, I do not know if I have to delete image from `MediaStore` when I do not need it anymore.

Comment: What you want to do with that path???? Depending in that the solution can be given

Comment: I need the path of image, because I need provide it into a sharing intent. See my `localPath` variable in my code, please.

Comment: @Clairvoyant See my update, please.